# object.size vs lobstr::obj_size in R

Tags: r

```
x <- runif(1e6)
y <- list(x, x, x)

object.size(y) 
24000224 bytes

lobstr::obj_size(y)
8,000,128 B
```

Please explain what makes these two functions different.

Comment: Did you check `?lobstr::obj_size`? It even has a section [*compared to `object.size`*](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lobstr/versions/1.1.1/topics/obj_size)...

Answer (score 4):

This is because object.size does not account for shared references. The object `y` does not comprise 3 different copies of `x` but 3 references to the same copy of `x`.

This can also be verified by the function `ref(y)` from the `lobstr` package where you can see that the 3 different components of `y` have the same address in memory.

Thus `object_size` is reporting approximately the same size for `x` and `y`, whereas `object.size` is multiplying the size by 3.